# Word online SSO - getAccessTokenAsync no respons no error

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js

I have created an Office add-in for Word Online but I can't get SSO working.

When the add-in is activated Word Online prompts the user for accepting the Add-in permissions, But I can’t get the SSO Token via Office.js.

When `getAccessTokenAsync()` first is called, I get no response or errors. If I call the function again I get error code `13008`. Which indicate that the operation is running, but the result is never returned.

**The manifest file is provided with**

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>00e69b3f-c86c-4764-9e6e-xxxxxxxx</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:43443/00e69b3f-c86c-4764-9e6e-xxxxxxxx </Resource>
    <Scopes>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
        <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
        <Scope>user.read</Scope>        
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
    </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

**Azure Endpoint v2 registration**

The add-in is registered at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Platform Web Api:

```
api://localhost:43443/00e69b3f-c86c-4764-9e6e-xxxxxxxx
```

Pre-authorized application:

```
bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3
57fb890c-0dab-4253-a5e0-7188c88b2bb4
d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c
```

Permissions:

```
openid
offline_access
user.read
Profile
```

I have granted administrator consent using
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=00e69b3f-c86c-4764-9e6e-xxxxxxxx&state=12345`

Update:

If the same manifest is sideloaded into Powerpoint online or Excel/Spreadsheet online it can get the token by calling getAccessTokenAsync(), but still not in Word Online

**Document Host**

```html
  <Hosts>
      <!--Each host can have a different set of commands. Cool huh!? -->
      <!-- Workbook=Excel Document=Word Presentation=PowerPoint -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
   


        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in. 
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
            <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
            <Title resid="dt.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
            <Description resid="dt.GetStarted.Description"/>

            <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL. 
       resid points to a Url resource -->
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="dt.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>

          <!--Function file is an html page that includes the javascript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called. 
            Think of the FunctionFile as the "code behind" ExecuteFunction-->
          <FunctionFile resid="dt.FunctionFile.Url" />
          

          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!--Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab -->
            <!-- Documentation includes all the IDs currently tested to work -->
            <CustomTab id="dt.Tab1">
              <!--Group ID-->
              <Group id="dt.Tab1.Group1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="dt.Tab1.GroupLabel" />
                <Icon>
                  <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
                  <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                  <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="dt.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="dt.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="dt.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                </Icon>

                <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="dt.LetterButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="dt.LetterButton.Label" />
                 
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="dt.LetterButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="dt.LetterButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="dt.LetterButton.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="dt.LetterButton.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="dt.LetterButton.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>ShowDialog</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="dt.PhraseButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="dt.PhraseButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="dt.PhraseButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="dt.PhraseButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="dt.PhraseButton.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="dt.PhraseButton.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="dt.PhraseButton.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>ShowDialog</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>          
              </Group>
              <Group id="dt.Tab1.Group2">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="dt.Tab1.GroupLabel2" />
                <Icon>
                  <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
                  <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                  <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="dt.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="dt.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="dt.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                </Icon>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="dt.SignonButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="dt.SignonButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="dt.SignonButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="dt.SignonButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="dt.SignonButton.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="dt.SignonButton.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="dt.SignonButton.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>OpenAccountStatus</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              
                 <Control xsi:type="Button" id="dt.SignonButton3">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="dt.SignonButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="dt.SignonButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="dt.SignonButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="dt.SignonButton.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="dt.SignonButton.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="dt.SignonButton.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">  
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>  
                    <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->  
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />  
                  </Action>  
                </Control>
              </Group>

              <!-- Label of your tab -->
              <!-- If validating with XSD it needs to be at the end, we might change this before release -->
              <Label resid="dt.Tab1.TabLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
```

Comment: I notice that your <Resource> element has a couple of blank spaces in it. Please remove those and try again. If that doesn't fix it, try using the Fiddler or Charles tool to capture the Request/Response from Office to AAD. Also, wait at least 31 seconds after the first attempt before you call getAccessTokenAsync again.

Comment: Blank spaces wasn't in the running code. Fiddler gives me nothing when the add-in is used in Word online. But if I use it in Powerpoint i get the token, and can aloso find it by using fiddler

Comment: I've asked the Microsoft product team for help. Someone will report back here what we discover.

Comment: While we're waiting, How many "Host" elements are in your manifest? Is there one for Presentation? Is there one for Document? Also, does it work on Word desktop? Does it work on PowerPoint Online?

Comment: Can you give us the Word host and PowerPoint host parts of your manifest, with personal info and GUIDs hidden? That gives us something to compare. Also, is the Word file you are opening in Word Online stored in the same place as the PowerPoint file that works in PowerPoint Online?

Comment: I have createted one manifest file for Word with hoste = Document and a copy of the file with hoste = Presentation. It works fine in powerpoint. 
I have both tried to sideloade the manifest and also pushed it from office online portal same result. I use onedrive to store document and presentation

Comment: The product team is requesting that you provide your entire manifest on GitHub and provide a link to it. Also, please have Fiddler running when you call getAccessTokenAsync with Word Online. Include the Fiddler records in the GitHub repo.

Comment: After resuming the project after 2 months of pause,i now get a response with a token. I have not changed any code.